# Nginx reverse proxy multiple backends

Tags: nginx

Here is my situation: I will have one frontend server running Nginx, and multiple backends servers running Apache + passenger with different rails applications. I am NOT trying to do any load balancing. What I need to do is setup Nginx to proxy connections to specific servers based on the URL. IE, `client.example.com` should point to `x.x.x.100:80`, `client2.example.com` should point to `x.x.x.101:80`, etc.

I am not that familiar with Nginx, but I could not find a specific configuration online that fit my situation.

Comment: hey were you able to find a solution for this? in my case i want same client to access to multiple of these backend servers, can you help me find a config for that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can match the different URLs with `server {}` blocks, then inside each server block, you'd have the reverse proxy settings.

Below, an illustration;

```
server {
  server_name client.example.com;

  # app1 reverse proxy follow
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://x.x.x.100:80;

}

server {
  server_name client2.example.com;

  # app2 reverse proxy settings follow
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://x.x.x.101:80;
}
```

Also, you may add further Nginx settings (such as `error_page` and `access_log`) as desired in each `server {}` block.

Comment: Is it possible to configure each origin server to be proxied based on path and not just incoming host/authority? I.e. `/system1/` is proxied to `http://x.x.x.100/` while `/system2/` is proxied to `http://x.x.x.120/`?

Comment: sure, in that case you simply place the proxy directives in an appropriate location block, instead of in the main server block

Comment: I put this in a config file inside sites-enabled and restarted the nginx and now I'm getting this error in logs: directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.domain.com

Comment: which directive is not allowed? (running `nginx -t` should tell you which directive on which line). What scope is the config block that directive is in (http/server/location)?

Comment: `proxy_pass` seems to not be allowed in server context

Comment: Why not add an upstream configuration?  This may make the configuration more clear. See [this example from official guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-upstreams/).

Comment: in which file should I write these? is it /etc/nginx/nginx.conf? or sites-enabled?

Answer (score 28):

@mohamnag's comment is right. `proxy_pass` is only allowed inside a `location`

See:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

So the correct config would be

```
server {
    server_name client.example.com;

    location / {
        # app1 reverse proxy follow
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.100:80;
    }
}

server {
    server_name client2.example.com;

    location / {
        # app2 reverse proxy settings follow
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.101:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: in which file should I write these? is it /etc/nginx/nginx.conf? or sites-enabled?

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev: "sites-enabled" is IMHO a Ubuntu related layout of configuration files and does only contain symlinks to the available sites in "sites-available". But yes, this should be placed inside the single site configurations under "sites-available".