# nginx reverse proxy multiple backends multiple processes

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I read the postings from this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240840/nginx-reverse-proxy-multiple-backends/25378825#25378825). I'm wondering if there is a way to run multiple instances in different processes? Because when I understand it right, running all instances in the same configuration file will create a common master and several worker processes. If the master process dies then all instances die at the same time.

From my perspective it would be better to run them separately, so that each backend system gets its own master. Do you agree? How could I achieve that?

Thankyou.

Comment: Why would master die?
How do you want several separate processes to listen to the same port?
To extend your fears, what if hardware dies?

Comment: Hi Alexey,How do you want several separate processes to listen to the same port? -> with virtual IPs, then the master would listen to another socket. To extend your fears, what if hardware dies? -> HA Cluster. Why would master die? -> Because of recompiling new modules, ... -> If I could seperate each master for one backend, I'm more flexible managing the other instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to use a HA Cluster. You'll use two master server configured in exactly the same way, and a balancer in front of them.

This configuration will hide a possible fault and will work in "reduced" mode.