# Multiple Node.js websites using one server

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to run multiple Node apps with Express on an Ubuntu server. I am using Nginx as a proxy with MP2 for my web server. It works fine for one website. Would like to set it up to run multiple sites under different domains using different ports. The setup should be able to restart automatically after a reboot. What would be the best practices solution to achieve my desired results?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240840/nginx-reverse-proxy-multiple-backends ?