# Apache listen and redirect to a different port

Tags: apache, freebsd, jail

I know this has been asked before, I used the highest rated question as a baseline, but I still can't get it to work.

I'm trying to host a website through an iocage jail in FreeBSD.

In my jail I'm hosting a domain called sub.domain.com. I've managed to get Apache to listen to a different port, 10080. So when I go to sub.domain.com:10080 I can access my website.

I would like to be able to go sub.domain.com and also access my website. As far as I understand, I need to redirect using mod_proxy to allow 80 -> 10080.

In httpd.conf I uncommented mod_proxy and added the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName www.sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:10080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10080
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work for me, I still have to go to sub.domain.com:10080 to access my website.

Any tips?

EDIT: current config, also doesn't work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName <jailip>
    ServerAlias <jailip>
    ProxyPass / http://<jailip>:10080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://<jailip>:10080
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Probably `localhost` resolves to `127.0.0.1` on your host, but your jail is most likely assigned on some other IP address, e.g. `127.0.0.2`.

Comment: I tried changing localhost to the actual IP of my jail, to no luck.

Comment: Is the jail assigned the external IP address for `sub.domain.com` in /etc/rc.conf? If so, and you're trying to configure Apache on the host, then your traffic will never reach Apache on the host. Instead, it'll be routed directly to the jail, and you can just let Apache in the jail listen on port 80.

Comment: No, I haven't configured the external IP in /etc/rc.conf. I have edited my post to reflect what I have now. I feel as if I am probably missing some more settings in httpd.conf.

Comment: Ok, let me get this staight. You have Apache on the host, and in the jail. The jail isn't assigned the IP number of sub.domain.com, only a private 127.0.0.X address. If so, then it can't possibly be the jail serving up sub.domain.com:10080 currently, unless you have also set up firewall rules to redirect traffic from the host to the jail.

Comment: But reading your re-phrased question, does httpd now only listen on port 10080 on the server assigned the IP of sub.domain.com? Check with `sockstat | grep httpd`. If it doesn't listen on port 80, then nothing in the VirtualHost config will change that.

Comment: I only have Apache running in the jail, which in this example is 127.0.0.111. Without changing the listen port, this is accessible as 127.0.0.111:80, which means I can access it by directly going to the IP. By changing the listen port to 10080, this is now accessible as 127.0.0.111:10080. As a first step, I would like to see if I can simply access the jail as 80 -> 10080, then I can figure out how to add sub.domain.com. `sockstat | grep httpd` indeed shows port 10080.

Comment: I would like to add that I am able to access my website with sub.domain.com:10080 if I port forward 10080 to 127.0.0.111, because sub.domain.com is the external IP of my local network.

Comment: Ok, so what you should do is: 1) Let Apache on the host listen on port 80, so it answers `http://sub.domain.com:80`. 2) Let Apache in the jail listen on `127.0.0.111:10080` (`127.0.0.111:80` would also work). 3) Add a VirtualHost entry to the host Apache config that has `ProxyPass / http://`127.0.0.111:10080`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would achieve step 1. I don't have two instances of Apache running. In the hosts record in my cPanel for my domain, I've forwarded my external IP to sub.domain.com. Then on my jail, which is in my localhost attached to my external IP, I'm running Apache on port 10080. Does this mean I have to forward the port in my cPanel?

Comment: If you're running Apache on port 10080, then it makes no sense to have a `<VirtualHost *:80>` entry in your httpd.conf, because Apache isn't even listening on port 80. It doesn't make sense to have a proxy setup either, because you only have one HTTP server running. If you want to reach `sub.domain.com` on port 80, then run Apache on port 80.

Comment: Maybe this can give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241111/1135424

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was sick. I can't use port 80 on my network, because port 80 is used by my routers login page. So when I try to go to my  <jail_ip>:80, I see nothing. However, when I listen on 10080 and go to <jail_ip>:10080, I see my webpage.